# Cream Cheese expiration dates

Tags: storage-lifetime, cream

The date on cream cheese does not say sell by or use by or best by. I wanted to make home made pimento & cheese, but I am somewhat reluctant to use it.

Comment: If you let it go long enough, the whole package will swell up.  (and this is why it's important to clean out your fridge once in a while ... those little blocks hide well when they're shoved behind things)

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you're exactly asking. Do you have cream cheese and are you asking if it is still good? Do you want to know how to know whether a cream cheese pimento is still good? Or how long it stays good? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

What country are you in? Is this Philadelphia Brand Cream Cheese? Is the package unopened? Does it have a Julian date on the package? Has it always been refrigerated?

As a *very* general rule, you can safely use unopened, always properly refrigerated cream cheese from a reputable source for 1 month past the sell-by date (this from [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17014) and other reputable sources). In the US, packages that have a date are supposed to also specify whether that date is a "use-by", "sell-by" or "best-by" date. Eggs are an exception.

Personally, I have used unopened cream cheese far beyond 1 month past the date on the package, but as far as that goes, it's your call. Use your common sense, assess your risk, and make a call for which you are ultimately responsible. No responsible person can tell you that unopened cream cheese is really good for 6 months past the date on the package, because that would make *that* person responsible if *your* cream cheese is an exception.

Answer (score 1):

The cream cheese I have let spoil always had quite clear indication of being spoiled: green hairs that would make most punk rockers jealous (i.e., mold).